# How to properly use pexpect for this case?

Tags: python, subprocess, pexpect

With pexpect.spawn , I have a program running in the background that sends back a line for each input line sent.
What would be the appropriate expect expression for getting the whole lines as output?
(after waiting until the line is there in the output)

I do not want to use any specific string (like a prompt), other than the newline to synchronize against.

I tried `myprogram.expect('\r\n')`, but it seems to contain the input along with the output.

Answer (score 0):

`I tried myprogram.expect('\r\n'), but it seems to contain the input along with the output.`
Does this mean the "\n" in input is considered?If yes, thereis a way to suppress the echo by setting `set echo` to false. You can try that.
Also can you paste the code that you are trying?